# Orchard Projection Query Performance

Tags: sql, performance, gridview, orchardcms

I've run into an issue with the Projection/Query feature of Orchard.  I am trying to use a Projection Widget to return a list of all my content items - there are ~3,000 in total.  The list needs to display just the TitlePart and a few related fields.  I have the View/Shape formatted the way I want it but if I try and load more than 100 results on a page the load time is almost a minute.

Ultimately I'm looking to produce a GridView layout with sortable columns.  The Projection/Query feature is so easy and nice but maybe not what I need if speed is an issue.  Any advice?  Is there a more appropriate way to query this number of items? Thanks!

Comment: You almost certainly have a select n+1 issue there. Profile it and find out.

Comment: Do you have shape tracing on? I have noticed in some cases shape tracing can slow down queries dramatically during development.